# Double bond crossed lines representation

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, structural-formula

I have been studying organic chemistry for years, and I do not remember the spotting double bond represented with crossed lines, except maybe one ore two more times in addition to the following one

[image]

which is taken from the [Aescin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aescin) Wikipedia graphics [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Beta-Aescin.svg).

I guess it is a drawing or rendering mistake, or a representation of unspecific *E*/*Z* configuration. If the latter is true, where can I find more info on usage of this symbol?

**UPDATE:**

A comment by gilleain leads to GRAPHICAL REPRESENTATION OF 
STEREOCHEMICAL CONFIGURATION (IUPAC Recommendations 2006). Relevant paragraph is:

> ...
>   The most common convention for depicting double bonds with unspecified configuration in molecules of all sizes uses a wavy bond.
>   ...
>   A crossed double bond has sometimes been used to indicate unspecified double bond configuration or a mixture of configurations. This type of bond is not considered acceptable for general use, although it may still be required by some computer software.

There's still missing piece of information about which software and by what means it "requires" this representation.

Comment: Looks like it's the second one - E/Z https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Skeletal_formula#Stereochemistry

Answer (score 8):

It is, for example, used by Marvin JS -- one of the editors in the GUI of Reaxys by Elsevier to query the database for structures, where you do not impose either (*E*)-, nor (*Z*)-configuration of the double bond.  Below an example if you were looking for both isomers of stilbene:

[image]

([demo version here](https://marvinjs-demo.chemaxon.com/latest/demo.html)).

Beside ChemDraw, ChemDoodle's sketcher ([here](https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/sketcher/)) and [PubChem's sketcher](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/edit2/index.html) are other examples of "some software" equally allowing such a representation, too.  I *speculate* it has something to do how databases (like ISISBase, Beilstein/Reaxys, Scifinder, for example) traditionally store(d) chemical structures and reaction schemes in a machine-readable format.

One may, for example, draw (*cis*)-stilbene with ChemDoodle "in the standard way" and save it as *.mol format and set this file in comparsion with the result of an undefined double bond with the using the wavy bond towards one of the phenyl rings.  In the chemical table, there is no significant difference spot:

[image]

If the "standard (*cis*) *.mol" file is compared with the one where the double bond is crossed -- as in the OP figure -- there is a difference on line #26 (fourth column now reads a three, instead of a zero), while maintaining the other entries:

[image]

This picture, naturally, differs from the *.mol files of classically specified (*cis*) and (*trans*) configuration:

[image]

used structures:

[image]